# Walking navigation with HERE sdk

Tags: android, here-api

I'm trying to create a route for pedestrian with HERE sdk for Android.
I tried changing RouteOptions.setTransportMode() to RouteOptions.TransportMode.PEDESTRIAN,
and changing Map.setMapScheme() to Map.Scheme.PEDESTRIAN_DAY but the route that I'm getting (displayed on the map) is for car navigation (e.g., it considers no entry traffic signs).
The HERE WeGo app (from Google Play) displays pedestrian routes correctly.
How can I build a route for pedestrians with HERE sdk for Android?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
In short:

```
routePlan = new RoutePlan();
routePlan.addWaypoint(new RouteWaypoint(new GeoCoordinate(lat, lon)));
routePlan.addWaypoint(new RouteWaypoint(target));

// These 4 lines solved the problem
RouteOptions ro = new RouteOptions();
ro.setTransportMode(RouteOptions.TransportMode.PEDESTRIAN);
ro.setRouteType(RouteOptions.Type.FASTEST);
routePlan.setRouteOptions(ro);

CoreRouter coreRouter = new CoreRouter();
...
```

I had to use setRouteOptions() correctly.